# how to use purrr with lubridate

Tags: r, purrr

Consider this simple example

```
mydata
List of 3
 $ : chr "11/12/2015"
 $ : chr "21/10/2015"
 $ : chr "04/09/2015"
```

I want to apply `lubridate::dmy()` to each character in this list.
Simply running

```
mydata %>% map(., lubridate::dmy(.))
Error: Can't convert a double vector to function
```

produces an error. What am I missing here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you included a `.` Your code would work just fine if you remove the `.`. In that case, you wouldn't have to include `~` and instruct `purrr::map` to treat this as a function with its arguments included in the function call.

Try the following:

```
mydata %>% 
purrr::map(.x = ., 
.f = ~ lubridate::dmy(.))
```

Comment: damn that works! any reason why my syntax confuses `map` ?

Comment: It's because you included a `.`. Your code would work just fine if you remove the `.`. In that case, you wouldn't have to include `~` and instruct `purrr` to treat this as a function with its own arguments included in the function call itself. Hope that helps.

Comment: As to your other question: `map(.x = ., .f = sprintf, "I want to include the string %. here"` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This goes wrong because `.` means two things in different contexts. In a pipe, it means the previous object in the pipe, but in `purrr` it can be a shorthand for the object going into the function to be mapped. It only represents the second when the `~` is included.

The above solution should work, but these should also. I don't think you need to include `.x = .` because it's the first argument and should be passed by the pipe. Again, easier to check with a reproducible example.

```
mydata %>% map(function(x) dmy(x))
mydata %>% map(~ dmy(x))
```

Comment: thanks! can I just ask a follow up then, how can I use `.` in `sprintf` ? say `map(., sprintf("I want to include the string %. here")`

Comment: You should use `str_c` to concatenate the strings, like this: `mydata %>% map(~ sprintf(str_c("I want to include the string ", ., " here")))`

Comment: Calum, I think Patil was first. Thanks again!!